# How can I get a list of questions posted from a certain IP address (a.k.a an organization)?

Tags: support

I read an article by David Robinson: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/15/how-do-students-use-stack-overflow

He filters questions posted by users at educational institutions identified by their ISP. I would like to do something like this for the company I work at.

Unfortunately, the appropriate query is not given. I tried to figure it out using  http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions but cannot find the appropriate fields in the filter selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible for mere users, you need to be a *Stack Exchange developer* with *direct access to the database* to do so. IP addresses are **personal information**, and while they are under circumstances [accessible to ♦ moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149637/295232) this wouldn't be sufficient to do a query like you propose.

Answer (score 3):

The API will never contain this information as it would be a major breach of trust (and possibly legally sanctionable, depending on the jurisdiction).

If you believe that you have a valid use for this data, you can contact the Stack Exchange team via the [Contact Us form](https://stackapps.com/contact) (linked in the footer) and explain your research objectives.

Be prepared to sign an NDA, at a minimum.